# "The local psql command could not be located" error Mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, heroku, psql

I am trying to connect to my heroku postgres database, but when i run

`heroku pg:psql --app DBNAME`

I get

`The local psql command could not be located.`

I have seen a few similar questions about this but none have really helped me. I tried running

`PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13.2\bin`

but no luck.

I have installed Postgres to my mac but even when I run `postgres -V` I get an error saying Postgres is not a command.

I am very new to all of this and very confused, so I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: mac or windows? Title says Mac, path is more like windows

Comment: Mac, maybe I am mixed up

Comment: How did you install Postgres on the Mac and from what source?

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users the path to pslq should be `/usr/local/bin` ( /usr/local/bin/psql )

and path should be somethinkg like: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin`

You can edit your path folders with `sudo nano /etc/paths` and add the corrects